Interpretation of hazard ratios - impact on time to event?
say I use Cox proportional hazards model where I explain time to some event with a number covariates. In the result, for each covariate I get the proportional hazard ratios (HR). A HR lower than 1 suggests that given covariate lowers the hazard of the event. I want to make sure I understand it correctly. Can I say that HR < 1 means that this it takes longer for the event to happen, but it does not say whether the effects take place or not (as this question is answered by a logit model)? For example, if I studied the impact of taking the medicine on the cardiac arrest, a HR < 1 would mean that taking the treatment prolonges the incidence of cardiac arrest and those who take the drug will experience health problems later?
Best

The HR measures the relationship of the covariate to the  instantaneous hazard of the event.
One trouble with equating this to "time to event" is that the events are typically censored, and the censored values could have any time -- for some models, the event might never occur for some cases. How would you average those?  You could try to compare medians, but even the median can be indeterminate if there is a lot of censoring.
And, at least theoretically, it might be that the treatment has some huge effect right after the censoring time, which would be problematic.

Best to distinguish raw data from distributional tendencies.

If a variable in a model has an HR <1, that means that a one-unit increase in thar variable decreases the likelihood of that event happening at any given time. What that means in terms of the event actually happening at all gets a little complicated.
One of the assumptions of survival analysis is that the event will eventually happen to everyone. We just won't always see it because of censoring. This makes intuitive sense when the event in question is death, but may not make as much sense for other outcomes. But if you stretch your brain a little bit you can usually get it to make sense.
If your "event" is having heart attack then all other forms of death represent "censorship due to competing event." If I get hit by a bus then you will never know if I would have had a heart attack the next day or week or year. Your model basically assumes the following: while not everyone will have a heart attack before they die, if we were all immune to all other forms of death the likelihood that we would all eventually have a heart attack approaches 1. That actually seems to me to be a reasonable enough assumption for this to make sense. But you don't need to go into all of this to interpret the hazard ratio. It just tells you that the event is more or less likely to happen at any given time period.
If there is a situation where it really doesn't make sense to assume that everyone will eventually experience the event then you would need to explore some other type of survival analysis model, like a mixture cure model.

Thanks a lot. How does the interpretation of the HR that you wrote  differ from the interpreteation of the logit model? For the same type of data that I use for survival analysis, I can simply estimate standard logit and get odds ratio. I don't fully understand what kind of different answers I get using these two types of model. I initially thought that survival results show me the impact on time to event, and logit shows probability of event, but I can see it's not that simple. Thank you for the suggestion regarding the mixture cure model.

The logit and cox model are totally different, answer different questions, and require the data to be set up in very different ways. The cox model requites both a continuous time to event variable and a binary "censored or not" variable, doesn't' compute an intercept, and estimates how each variable changes the hazard of the event happening at a particular time. A logit model predicts whether something happened or not. Trying to run a logit model on survival data would basically amount to predicting whether the data were censored, and just ignoring all of the data on time-to-event.

I know that data setup is different, but in the SA data there is information whether the event happened or not (in the observation period ofc), so you can run logit. You wrote that both model "answer different questions". This is what I'm trying to understand. What is the difference in interpretation of odds ratio from logit of 0.93 and hazard ratio from SA of 0.93?

In SA data there is info on whether you know WHEN the event happened (censorship) that's not the same thing as info on whether the event happened.  Logit ORs and Cox HR are so different that it's hard to even summarize all the differences in a comment. One model is nonlinear and the other is not. They include different information, make different assumptions, one measures odds and the other measures likelihoods (which are very different but often confused). I'd recommend digging back into the basic lit on survival analysis to get a better handle on this.
